# £ sign in url causes bad request in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, wss-3.0, bad-request

We have a file in sharepoint with a £ sign as part of the url.

When we try to retrieve this file we get a bad request.

Interesting thing is that this is only a problem in production not in test.

Anyone know what setting could be causing this difference?

Comment: Not a solution - but this symbol in a URL? I'd try to revise the url causing this error instead of investing time into working this issue out with IIS + Sharepoint.

Comment: Does replacing the £ with %A3 in the URL work? I'm inclined to agree with moontear.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the registry or IIS 7.0 configuration on the production server?

[Ampersand & the Request URL in IIS7](http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/) (not a £ article but might be related)

Comment: Thanks, but No it is wss-3.0 therefore iis 6.0

Comment: The registry setting applies to IIS6.0 as well I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are trying to access an url like one of these?

[http://foo.com/api/getfile/foo£bar.txt](http://foo.com/api/getfile/foo%C2%A3bar.txt)

http://foo.com/api/getfile/foo%A3bar.txt

If so I think it may be related to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037000/134761

Try rewriting the url to
http://foo.com/api/getfile?file=foo%A3bar.txt