# when executing my autocomplete, i got this error. what should i do?

Tags: c#

this is the output:

```
http://localhost:50015/localhost:50015/CustomerJSON/getAutocomplete?&field=Id&field=Name&search_var=term&search_field=Name&json_key_prop=id&json_value_field=Id&json_key_prop=label&json_value_field=Name&json_key_prop=value&json_value_field=Name&term=a
400 (Bad Request)
```

this is the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request. Path value was detected from the client (:)

I use a design pattern from my company, they have a framework for jquery and then this happens when I create an autocomplete. Has anyone of you ever got this kind of error?

Comment: yes, there is a duplicate URL.. but i dont remember if i ever put a second URL, that is just appear when i create my autocomplete from my framework

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257811/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with your address: the `localhost:50015` appears twice in a row. The second part with the `:` causes the error.

Comment: yes, i just want to mention that.. but thank for finding my problem, but how can it be ? i never add any second url in my code, how is it posible ?

Comment: Without your code, that will be hard to answer.

Comment: amnBuildAutoCompleteURL('txtName', 'CustomerJSON/getAutocomplete', 'Id', 'Name', 'Id', 'Name', onSelectFunc, onBackspaceFunc);

Comment: amnBuildAutoComplete is a function from my framework

Comment: in it function require an element, url, parameter, and an object

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code.

Comment: thank, ahh i am so dumb