# IIS allowing colon in URL route

Tags: api, http, url, iis, iis-8

We have a C# MVC application that contains a call to an endpoint that is formatted like this

> `VerifyMe/12345/Password:Reset`

On 2 servers, both with no Request Filtering set and our application having no web.config entry for `httpRuntime` `requestPathInvalidCharacters`, one server (IIS 10) is allowing the request through and one server (IIS 8) is returning a `400 Bad Request` (due to the colon)

I cannot find anywhere that talks about the valid characters changing between the 2 versions

Is there anything else that could be making the IIS 8 server return a 400 for that URL?

Comment: Windows HTTP API is where incoming requests are parsed and handled initially after landing on a Windows machine, and due to security consideration its behaviors can change from time to time, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/site-behavior-performance/error-logging-http-apis

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is the colon, which on Windows (and DOS) based systems is a reserved character for file structures and can give you all kinds of problems.

It seems that ASP.net doesn't allow a colon before `"?"`, even though it is encoded as `%3A` in the URL. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066188/url-encoded-colon-resolves-in-400-bad-request).